# Multiplicative Inverses

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I'm working on this question...

> What is the multiplicative inverse of $3+2[x]$ in the field $\mathbb{Q[x]}/(x^2+7)$

I have been searching throughout this website on how to do such problems related to this one because there aren't any examples of it on my book. According to what I have found on similar questions, I would have to, in some way, implement Euclidian division to $x^2+7$. Since $x^2+7$ is irreducible, the $gcd$ with any other polynomial will yield $gcd = 1$. What would I do next, if I'm even in the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly.  You want to find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(x)(3+2x)=1$ in your field.  Because we are taking out $x^2+7$ we might guess that a linear polynomial will work because we can get rid of quadratic terms.  So we write $(ax+b)(3+2x)=2ax^2+(3a+2b)x+3b=(3a+2b)x+(3b-14a)=1$
This gives us two simultaneous equations $3a+2b=0, 3b-14a=1$ which we can solve for $a$ and $b$.  I essentially used the Euclidean algorithm when I replaced $x^2$ by $-7$.

Comment: As suggested by your answer, I have the values $a = -\frac{2}{37}$ and $b = \frac{3}{37}$. To yield the multiplicative inverse, I would simply substitute $a$ and $b$ in the expression $(ax+b)$ correct?

Comment: I double checked the math on a calculator and the values for $a$ and $b$ seem to be correct. The process is what matters to me, not so much the numbers, since it's basic arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, that is right.  Intuitively, if you multiply $3+2x$ by its conjugate $3-2x$ you get the difference of squares $9-4x^2$ and the $x^2$ goes away to give you a constant.  You can divide that out.

Comment: Yes, what you suggested works as well.